# ARQ query for blank node

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, arq, blank-nodes

I am working on RDF query language. So, I have installed Apache Jena.
RDF data is given below:

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xlmns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

_:a foaf:name  "Alice" .
_:b foaf:name  "Ashish" .
```

And ARQ query is:

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?x ?name
WHERE { ?x foaf:name ?name }
```

Problem — my result is:

```
+---+------+
| x | name |
+---+------+
+---+------+
```

The correct result is:

```
+-----+---------+
|  x  |  name   |
+-----+---------+
| _:c | "Alice" |
| _:d | "Bob"   |
+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix in your data is wrong.  The query correctly uses **xmlns**, but the data has a typo, **xlmns** (the "l" and "m" are swapped).

Comment: Ohh !! Blunder mistake. Thank you Joshua Tayar